# CSS fluid layout for inputs

Tags: html, css, input, fluid-layout

I am currently making a website and the sign up page requires:
- first name
- last name
- username
- email
- password
- retype password
I need the first name and last name inputs to be side by side and small while the others below them are approximately twice the width.
Like this:

```
 Name
+-----------+    +-----------+
| first     |    | last      |
+-----------+    +-----------+

 Email
+----------------------------+
|                            |
+----------------------------+
```

I am *extremely* opposed to using `px` and absolutely need to use `%` for the widths.
I cannot make the small inputs `50%` and the large ones `100%` because the space in between the two small ones is not accounted for, you know?
I'm talking about *this* space:

```
 Name
+-----------+    +-----------+
| first     |<-->| last      |
+-----------+    +-----------+
```

So that is why I can't use `50%` for small ones and `100%` for large ones!
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple do this:

call the small ones : half

```
.first {margin-left: 0 !important; clear: left;}
.full {width:100%}
.half {width: 48%;}
.half {float: left; margin-left: 2%;}

<div class="first half">First Name</div>
<div class="half">Last Name input</div>
<div class="full">Email Input</div>
```

As you can see I used margin % to make the spacing...which thats how I made 48% -2%(you can do whatever you like as long as it equals..).
I made a class called ***.first*** to make things look right (you can use jquery to create this an auto class).

Heres a Fiddle:

[**FIDDLE THAT**](http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/ykNFV/)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you everyone who replied, these posts really helped. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/Lp2RF/)

```
<form>
  <input name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="small left"/>
  <input name="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" class="small"/>
  <input name="username" type="text" placeholder="User Name" class="big"/>
  <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-mail" class="big"/>
  <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="big"/>
  <input name="rpassword" type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" class="big"/>
  <button name="submit" type="">Sign Up</button>
</form>


form {
  background: #555;
  width: 350px;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
button {
  background: #04a9e8;
  position: relative;    
  margin: 25% auto;
  width: 140px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
button:hover {
  background: #02b9fc;
}
.small,
.big {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  height: 22px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #444;    
}
.small:focus,
.big:focus {
  background: #fff;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #0296cc;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 #0296cc;
}
.small {
  width: 45.5%;
}
.big {
  width: 98.1%;    
}
.left {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Have you read the post? you are using pixels.. and also please show only what OP is asking for.. don't encourage by giving complete code. you are providing the code more than too much here.. It seems you copied this from somewhere else. (if it so, always mention the source).

Comment: Thank you @Mr_Green, you gave me a smile :) I'm doing this job for years now, (this is my free time) and this code is writen when this question popped up. And notice, I've not use pixels on input fields ;)

Comment: you are great. Just explain your code so that from next time yours will be the selected answer. Have a nice day :).

Comment: Ok @Mr_Green, next time I'll add an explanation to my answer, somethimes I'm tired, I wrote this answer about 06:30AM (no sleep), when I have time I like to give solutions rather than plain answers, for future ones who recently start coding to pick up some new stuff, I almost always first make a Fiddle with simple answer, then update it a couple of times. BTW I like your blog, it's nice & clean ;)

Comment: haha.. I am happy to hear that you like it. this makes you the first one to say it :). Thanks.

Comment: It's clean and simple, real blog, for easy reading, not like some blogs with colorfull backgrounds etc. which make you crazy after 10 min's.

Answer (score 0):

if you apply 100% with on input element it will overflow the div box because input element has some default padding, for perfect solution you should use this:

Your CSS:

```
input{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */
}
.clearfix { clear: both; }
.first, .last{ width: 48%; }
.first{ float: left; }
.last{ float: right; }
.email{ width: 100%;}
```

Your HTML:

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <label>Name</label><br>
    <input type="text" class="first">
    <input type="text" class="last">
</div>
<div class="clearfix">
    <label>Email</label><br>
    <input type="text" class="email">
</div>
```

You can checkout this page to know how to align layout with float - http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/css-alignment.php